# How to compare vector results with AVX2 64bit comparsion?

Tags: c++, avx2

I'm trying to compare two vector with sse2, but it seems that the `_mm256_testz_si256` function doesn't work as expected.

```
bool is_equal(const std::vector<uint64_t>& vec1, const std::vector<uint64_t>& vec2, std::size_t s) {
  uint64_t* data1 = const_cast<uint64_t*>(vec1.data());
  uint64_t* data2 = const_cast<uint64_t*>(vec2.data());
  __m256i v1, v2, v3, v4;
  size_t start = 0;
  while (start < s) {
    v1 = _mm256_loadu_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i*>(data1 + start));
    v2 = _mm256_loadu_si256(reinterpret_cast<__m256i*>(data2 + start));
    __m256i r1 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi64(v1, v2);
    bool mask = _mm256_testz_si256(r1, r1) == 0;
    if (!mask) return false;
    start += 4;
  }
  return true;
}

  std::vector<uint64_t> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 12};
  std::vector<uint64_t> vec2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
  std::cout << is_equal(vec, vec2, vec.size()) << std::endl;
```

I'm not familiar with the Intel Intrinsics functions, so if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong, it would be appreciated.

Comment: "Doesn't work as expected"? What does "doesn't work" mean and what is expected?

Comment: @j6t thanks for answer. On the 3rd round, comparing [9,0,1,12] with [9,10,11,12], the mask value should be false. But it's true.

Comment: You're checking that the compare result vector has at least one non-zero bit.  If that's not what you want, don't do that.  e.g. use `_mm256_movemask_epi8` and check that the mask is `-1`.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks! I use the function _mm256_testz_si256 wrongly.